# Find the last part of a string

Tags: c#, regex

I am really not good at using RegEx, it struggles me a lot every time when I try to use it.
I Have a string:

```
        "aaa bbb ccc - ddd eee fff - xxx yyy zzz";
```

What I try to get is the substring after the last ' - '

If I use pattern "^.* - (.*)$" like below it does't work.

```
        string pattern = "aaa bbb ccc - ddd eee fff - xxx yyy zzz";
        Match match = Regex.Match(pattern, @"^.* - (.*)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

what pattern can make match.Captures.Count equals 1, and match.Captures[0].Value equals "xxx yyy zzz"?

I have to use Regex, because I have a generic function, and the pattern is a parameter.

What the pattern should be?

Background:

I have a function alreay deploied in production, the main job of that function is:

```
        ..............................
        string name = xxx;
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
        Match match = regex.Match(name);
        if (match != null)
        {
           for (int index = match.Captures.Count - 1; index > 0; index--)
              name = name.Remove(match.Captures[index].Index, match.Captures[index].Length);

        }
        xxx = name;
        ...........................
```

Comment: Why does it not work?  `match.Groups[1]` seems like what you want.

Comment: According to your regex, what you want is Groups[1]. What do you expect Groups[0] should return?

Comment: Do you say, I want a regex that return what i want without using any groups?

Comment: Why? .....and what does it mean? Is this a real question or just kidding? Vote as *unclear what you're asking*

Comment: I just ask what the pattern should be, I don't understand why this question is not clear.

Comment: Half an hour people try to answer your question and only now (after your last edit) it is clear what your real problem is. Very bad question with a 1K rep people.

Comment: `I just ask what the pattern should be` You don't ask only for pattern (since yours works already), you also impose other restrictions like the number of groups of regex. **-1**

Comment: **Ha ha** You accepted an answer using `Substring+LastIndexOf` instead of regex. If you had asked that, you may have got many other answers BTW: I felt like I talk to myself since all other comments are removed :)

Comment: No I accepted the regex edition,(.)(?<=- )([^-])+$ works for me.

Comment: People think this is a bad question,  first I tried to delete the comments and  then when I tried to delete this, but it is now allowed. Sorry for this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Regex is, yet again, overkill for this sort of thing. Just use `LastIndexOf`:

```
var result = pattern.Substring(pattern.LastIndexOf("-") + 1);
```

Output: `xxx yyy zzz`

EDIT:

Regex version: `(.)(?<=- )([^-])+$`. Don't bother matching from the start of the string (using `^`).. you only care about the end.

Not sure why you need this though. I would be interested to see your "non-simplified" version of your function.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I have to use Regex, because I have a generic function, and the pattern is a parameter.

Comment: RegEx, what have you become? Too powerful for string extraction, too weak for HTML parsing...

Comment: Why do you have to use regex? The regex you're using still looks for the dash.. This does the same thing.. just without Regex.

Comment: the the function is using regex, I just simplified the question,in order to make it easy.

Comment: I still doubt you require Regex. However I have updated my answer to provide a working pattern.

Comment: Sorry, Simon, How could I get only one match, I mean match.Groups.Count == 1. Using your pattern, I got Groups[0] ->" iiiiii 9999999"; Groups[1] -> ' '; Groups[2] -> "9". "iiiiii 9999999" is only the thing I want to get.

Comment: You want group 2.. since there are 3 sets of parenthesis in the expression (and C# arrays are 0-based).